# Why is CreateObject with a dot-notation path to the component not working using CF Administrator Mappings that define the path to the CFC directory?

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-2016, createobject

I am working on a web app already on the production server based on CF code that uses and depends on the CF Administrator Mappings to locate CFCs. I have a directory structure like this:

```
Webroot/
  _TaskDir/
    Application.cfm
    myFile.cfm
  CFC/
    component1.cfc
    ...
  app/
    Application.cfm
    index.cfm
    ...
```

My Mappings in CF Administrator has something like:

```
Logical Path: /myComponents
Directory Path: C:/Projects/Code/.../CFC/
```

Most of the app is under the app directory and uses calls to create objects all over the place like:
`<cfset myCFCojb = CreateObject("component", "myComponents.component1").init()>`

There are some scheduled task type scripts in another folder at the webroot (`_TaskDir`) that calls the `CreateObject` method in the same way as everywhere else, using the dot notation to specify the path to the components mapped directory. It supposedly has been working fine on production but for some unknown reason I am finding it doesn't work in this directory in my dev environment. The `CreateObject` works fine in the rest of my app, but when put into scripts in this folder it fails.

By fails, I mean i get a `NullPointerException` error. If I change the dot-notation path to a physical path (since both paths are within the webroot) such as `CreateObject("component", "/CFC/component1").init()` then  it's fine. It's just the dot notation and mappings that seem to be ignored in just this directory.

Is this because this folder is outside the app directory which has the main `Application.cfm` and that `_TaskDir` has it's own `Application.cfm`? I would think the Mappings would work for either.

The first part of the stackTrace is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   coldfusion.util.Utils.getDirectoryFromPath(Utils.java:350) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getTemplateFileHelper(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1638)
>   at
>   coldfusion.cfc.ComponentProxyFactory.getProxy(ComponentProxyFactory.java:51)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6354) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6373)...

I am using CF2016 in a Tomcat container.

Comment: The directory path does not seem to match the sample directory structure you provided.

Comment: Scott, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited it above.

Comment: Just a note: Are you using `Application.cfm` or `Application.cfc`? You get a lot more out of the `.cfc` flavor.

Comment: Is there another Application.cfm file in the folder (or path leading to the web root) on your dev environment that is overriding the mapping?

Comment: We are using older code and still use only Application.cfm. As shown above, both directories each have just one file called Application.cfm. However, there is an older Application.cfm.orig (MS Visual Studio Code tends to create them) and another called Application_apr15.cfm. Each Application.cfm does have cfincludes to other files that set variables (mostly).

Comment: When this code was written there was no support for external mappings structure. I have not see evidence that another file is present that could overwrite the CF Administrator mappings.

At this point I am suspecting there is something about my dev environment. I have checked with another developer working with the same code base and CF Admin mappings work fine in this same folder location. Production server also hasn't had issues with this. Something about my setup is off and I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Since this is a legacy code base running on a modern version of CF, it might be well worth your time to try to upgrade some of this code. The benefits you could gain by using some of the more modern features (even just Application.cfc vs .cfm) may completely eliminate some of the problems you see.

Comment: And one thing I would do is verify "It supposedly has been working fine on production". Do you see it actually work in production the way it's supposed to work?

Comment: Does your user have appropriate permissions to access your local `_TaskDir` folder?

Comment: Shawn, we try to upgrade when we can find time but it takes a back seat to new bug fixes and dev. I've mentioned converting to Application.cfc but that is likely not to happen yet given the impact of testing the whole app as a result.
Your point about checking for myself on production is difficult as I don't have control or access to do that. There are scheduled jobs that use these scripts there and since it has been proven to be delivering results these scripts are responsible for, I believe they are working.

Comment: However, many/most of these scripts are using objects that are already created within the /app space and therefore the CreateObject may be bypassing the need for the CreateObject within these scripts here. I plan to get clarity on that asap.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Found out that the version of Tomcat (8.5.20) I am using as the container for my Apache server is now case sensitive. I ran 3 scripts from my _TaskDir directory specifying the URL with the wrong case (_Taskdir), first 2 ran fine. The 3rd was the one that was trying to run CreateObject using Administrator Mappings to find the CFC directory. The URL is apparently being used to comparie with the Mappings paths. With the  wrong case being used in the URL is impacting the dot-notation path to the CFC directory.  At least I know how to resolve this now.

If you can shed more light on how this case sensitive paths is impacting CF, I'd like to know more. If there is an article on this, please share.

Comment: Coming from a case-insensitive background in, say Windows, it can catch us off guard when we fall into other languages or systems that _ARE_ case-sensitive, like Tomcat and even Java. I think there are flags in both systems that can turn case-sensitivity on or off, but I'm not sure what they are off the top of my head.